# Sharepoint List won't display in New Experience

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-2013

Help! Sharepoint List won't display in New Experience!

I have a list in Sharepoint and I want it to be displayed in New Experience but it won't, even though my Library Settings List experience was set to "New Experience" it still displays the list in CLASSIC experience.

I understand that sometimes it takes time to take effect the new experience but I have set it to new experience for about 4 days now.

[My Library Setting Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FryP.png)

Would greatly appreciate an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint Online, there is a link which can switch classic experience and New experience, in the list view page left bottom:

[image]

Click this link, the list will change to New experience.